# git push -u origin master remote: Permission to user android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, android-studio-2.1

I was changed user for github in Android studio and trying to pushing code in repository but its getting error.

Repository successfully creating and commit also but in pushing time getting error.

```
F:\....>git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to abc.in/abc.git denied to olduser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://..../abc.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I also tried new project, but still getting old user name denied access error.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with git. Maybe the credentials of the user you are using has changed? Try connecting to the server: `ssh username@hostname`. Use the username you are having problem with instead of `username` and use the server's name or ip instead of `hostname`. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why don't you push using Android Studio?
2. Have you got write permission on remote for new user?
3. Did you changed user in repo too? I think that you still have old data. Check it in project directory

   > git config user.name
   >
   > git config user.email
4. You can check this trick

   > edit .git/config file under your repo directory
   >
   > find url=entry under section [remote "origin"]

   change it from

   > url=https://your_user_name@github.com/yy/repo_name.git

   to

   > url=ssh://git@github.com/your_user_name/repo_name.git.
5. Alternatively

   1. Create new repo in your remote server  <- can be skipped
   2. Remove existing git remote from local project

      > git remote rm origin
   3. Add new remote

      > git remote add origin https://github.com/your_user_name/repo.git

I have no more idea :)